# Why is my palindrome checker always evaluating to true? I tried to debug, and my results are different

Tags: java, palindrome

Just trying to check if the input is a palindrome. Code keeps evaluating to true, but upon debugging, my answers are false;

Maybe I'm confused with == vs .equals?

```
class Solution {
    public boolean isPalindrome(int x) {
        int orig = x;
        String result = x + "";
        char[] original = result.toCharArray();
        String compare = "";

        if(orig < 10) {
            return true;
        }

        for(int i = original.length-1; i >= 0; i--) {
            compare += original[i];  
        }

        //System.out.println(result); -121
        //System.out.println(compare); 121
        if(result == compare) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }   
    } 
}
```

Comment: `if(result compare) {` Is this your real code?

Comment: The logic to check palindrome isn’t correct. You should check solutions on regarding this online. The link above should do it.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you used `(result==compare)`
Replace it with `result.equals(compare)`

Comment: Won’t work if the number is negative

Comment: Can you explain why? @HarshalParekh The string contents are still different?

Comment: Based on the logic of the code, if a number is negative, say -121, @learning is trying to convert it to a string and then reverse it. In this case, you’re comparing -121 with 121- which logically is a palindrome, but your logic will return false. Your solution only fixes the problem with positive numbers.

Comment: I am not sure about this but can a negative number be a palindrome?